# Changing background image of element to match that of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have the background image of a holder div change when I click on the div of another element.  The background image needs to change to that of the clicked div.  How would I go about doing this?  I figured the following script would work, but it's only changing it to that of the last image in the object.

**HTML**

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="plane_image"></div>
    <div id="sub_menu"></div>
</div>
```

Object that holds the images and other information

```
var Plane_Images = {
    Skin: {
        src: "images/Top.png"
    },
    Structure: {
        name: "Structure Schematic",
        src: "images/ata21.png"
    },
    Electrics: {
        name: "Electrics Schematic",
        src: "images/ata26.png"
    },
    Fuel: {
        src: "images/Top.png"
    }
}
```

Sets the background image for clickable divs

```
for(var images in Plane_Images){
    var id = images.toLowerCase();
    var image_src = Plane_Images[images].src;
    var schematic = $("<div data-id='" +id +"_menu'><div class='label'><p>" +images +"</p></div></div>");
    schematic.addClass("schematics");
    schematic.css("background-image", "url(" +image_src +")");

    $("#menu").append(schematic);
}
```

This is where I want to set the background image to match that of the clicked div in the previous loop.

```
$(".schematics").on("click", function(){
    $("#plane_image").css("background-image", "url(" +image_src +")");
    console.log(image_src);
})
```

Right now, the console is returning `images/Top.png` which is the image for the first and the last div, regardless of which div I click on.

Comment: It's in the HTML, I'll add it to the question

Comment: set the url in data attribute and change it on click... will that work?

Comment: Could you add a fiddle for it

Comment: @Kalish you mean something like `data-url="objectkey.src"`?

Comment: @Kushal, I could, but you wouldn't see the images, of course I could simply change the background-image to background-color

Comment: Yes, while setting the background image, u store the url data-url="objectkey.src" and while on click function you replace accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this should work.....first set the URL in data-url and then on click retrieve and change it to main div.

in the for loop update the line to this ....

```
var schematic = $("<div data-id='" +id +"_menu' data-url='" +image_src +     "'><div class='label'><p>" +images +"</p></div></div>");

$(".schematics").on("click", function(){
var url = $(this).data('url')
$("#plane_image").css("background-image", url);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to adapt your code to this:

```
$(".schematics").on("click", function(){
    $("#plane_image").css("background-image", $(this).css('background-image'));
    console.log($(this).css('background-image'));
})
```

You can use `$(this)` in an event to get the element that has been clicked.

Comment: That tells me how to see what background image is associated with which clicked element, not how to change the `#plane_image` div to match it.

Comment: @User the 2nd line of my code is changing the `#plane-image` css to match backgrounds.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see that.  Sorry